# How to sort <li> elements and put the results

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, sorting

I am making an online exam for nursery kids, in this exam, I have some list `<li>` elements comprising of scattered numbers from 0-6, e.g:

```
<ul>
  <li> <div>3</div></li>
  <li> <div>0</div></li>
  <li> <div>4</div></li>
  <li> <div>6</div></li>
  <li> <div>1</div></li>
  <li> <div>2</div></li>
  <li> <div>5</div></li>
</ul>
```

I used jQuery sortable to make it sortable, so the kids just have to drag the list of number boxes to be in right order of 0,1,2,3.. that works fine. The problem now is how do I check if they sorted it correctly and  display the wrong answer and the correct answer.

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: If you can't, or won't, share your "*[mcve]*" code your question may be closed as off-topic due to the lack of code. Please read the guidance provided, including "*[ask]*."

Comment: This question doesn't require any code. All that the OP wants is a method to get an array from the ordering of a `ul` tag.

Answer (score 1):

You could to it like this: Check if the `index()` of the `<li>` equals the text inside its `<div>`. If so, it's at the correct position.

```js
$("ul").sortable();
$("#check").on("click", function() {
  $("ul li").each(function() {
    if ($(this).index() == $(this).find("div").text()) {
      $(this).addClass("right");
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("wrong");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.wrong {
  color:red;
}
.right {
  color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>3</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>0</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>4</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>6</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>1</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>2</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>5</div>
  </li>
</ul>
<button id="check">
  Check
</button>
```

Another option is to check for the right or wrong position directly after an element was sorted using the `update` event of `sortable()`:

```js
$("ul").sortable({
  update: function() {
    $("ul li").each(function() {
      if ($(this).index() == $(this).find("div").text()) {
        $(this).addClass("right");
      } else {
        $(this).addClass("wrong");
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.wrong {
  color:red;
}
.right {
  color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>3</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>0</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>4</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>6</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>1</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>2</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>5</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

If you want to add a message if each element is at the correct or wrong position, you could do it as follows:

```js
$("ul").sortable({
  update: function() {
    let result = [];
    $("ul li").each(function() {
      if ($(this).index() == $(this).find("div").text()) {
        $(this).addClass("right");
        result.push($(this).find("div").text() + " is at the correct position.<br/>");
      } else {
        $(this).addClass("wrong");
         result.push($(this).find("div").text() + " is at the wrong position.<br/>");
      }
    });
    $("#result").html(result);
  }
});
```

```css
.wrong {
  color:red;
}
.right {
  color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>3</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>0</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>4</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>6</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>1</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>2</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>5</div>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="result">
</div>
```

Comment: Good answer.If you could just output correct answer and wrong answer. Using Array.some() you can stop the iteration instead of checking each element and applying class right or wrong.Thoughts?

Comment: @Supercool.Thanks for your input. I've updated my answer with an approach to add messages about the correctness of each element's position.

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is have two arrays of numbers, one is the original ordered one and the other is randomly ordered one. Then you can render list items in the order of the randomized array. Use event handlers for `drag`, `drop`, and `dragover` to capture the `innerText` of the element you are dragging as well as the `innerText` of the element that is being dragged over. Now that you have those values, you can get the index of both of them in the randomized array, remove the item at the index of the element being dragged and then insert it at the index of the element being dragged over. These operations can be achieved using `splice`. See the snippet below.

```js
var list = document.getElementById('list')
var nums = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var dragging, draggedOver;
var randomNums = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var isRight = 'Not in order!';

const genRandom = () => {
  randomNums = randomNums.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)
  renderItems(randomNums)
}

const renderItems = (data) =>{
  document.getElementById('isRight').innerText = isRight
  list.innerText = ''
  data.forEach(num=>{
    var node = document.createElement("li");    
    node.draggable = true
    node.addEventListener('drag', setDragging) 
    node.addEventListener('drop', compare) 
    node.addEventListener('dragover', allowDrop)
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(`${num}`);
     node.appendChild(textnode);
    list.appendChild(node)
  })
  dragging = null
  draggedOver = null
}

const compare = (e) =>{
  var index1 = randomNums.indexOf(dragging);
  var index2 = randomNums.indexOf(draggedOver);
  randomNums.splice(index1, 1)
  randomNums.splice(index2, 0, dragging)
 
  if (randomNums.join("") === nums.join("")){
    isRight = 'In order!'
  } else {
    isRight = 'Not in order!'
  }
  renderItems(randomNums)
 
};

function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    draggedOver = parseInt(ev.target.innerText)
}

const setDragging = (e) =>{
  dragging = parseInt(e.target.innerText)
}

genRandom()
```

```css
#container{
  width: 300px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

p {
  float: right;
}

#list li{
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
<ul id='list'>
</ul>
<p id='isRight'></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

example you list is like this.

```html
    <ul id="test">
    <li>0</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    </ul>
```

you can have the code list this
    function checkAnswer() {
      var answer = true;
      $("#test li").each(function(i, li) {
        answer = parseInt($(li).text(), 10) === i;
      });
      return answer;
    }

```
function getList() {
  var list = [];
  $("#test li").each(function(i, li) {
    list.push($(li).text());
  });
  return list.join(", ");
}

var ans = checkAnswer();
if (!ans) {
  console.log(getList() + " is not sorted");
} else {
  console.log(getList() + " is sorted");
}
```